# How to find correct type for map elements?

Tags: node.js, typescript

The below code outputs `[ 5142, 5143 ]`, but I use `any` as type.

```
let a = [{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }];

a = a.map((e: any) => {
  return e._id;
});

console.log(a);
```

[Looking at the types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) I would think the correct type would be

```
a = a.map((e: { _id: number }) => {
```

but it fails.

I use VSCode. Can it tell me the correct type? Or is there a clever `console.log(typeof)` trick?

Comment: Why does it fail?

Comment: I would type the array, map should infer the type automatically `let a: ({ _id: number })[] = [{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }];`

Comment: *"but it fails"* In what way? With what error?

Comment: Note that unless you define the type of `a` as a union, you can't assign the array you're creating in the `map` back to `a`. The type of `a` will be inferred as `{ _id: number; }[]`, but your `map` call is creating `number[]`.

Comment: You're trying to assign `number[]` to `Array<{_id: number}>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, assign the result of `map` to something else, not to `a`, since if you assign back to `a` then `a` has to be defined as `number[] | { _id: number; }[]` (since it starts out being `{ _id: number; }[]` and then you're trying to turn it into `number[]`).

If you assign it to something else, then you don't need to specify any types at all, TypeScript will infer them correctly:

```typescript
const a = [{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }];

const b = a.map((e) => {
    return e._id;
});

console.log(b);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gbxgfQJYBMBcMArAIwAsATDAL4A0MGOBx5AzDQLoDcAUD6JFgAjJPAB0AWzgAHABSyApgEokAPgY8YWmACcFUAK46wMBWKa9qS3v3AQQAGzMOQAc1lDrQA)

It's *possible* to reuse `a`, but it's not clear why you'd want to. Here's what that would look like, but I **don't** recommend it:

```typescript
let a: number[] | { _id: number; }[] = [{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }];

a = a.map((e) => {
    return e._id;
});

console.log(a);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwNoF0IB8IBvCAfQEsATOJNTAbggF9cIBeCLEi6iAVgCMAFgBMzADTEyVOIKEBmZjnoAoFVHbQAdMigAHABQGQASnYA+Yiog2IGcIgzwIILT1VMTqlQGMA9vAAzn6gWsB+AOYGUF5AA)

TypeScript's flow analysis lets it see that when calling `map`, `a` is a `{ _id: number; }[]`, so we don't need a type guard. If it weren't obvious from context, you would:

```typescript
function example(a: number[] | { _id: number; }[]) {
    a = a.map((e) => {
        return typeof e === "object" ? e._id : e; // Note the type guard
    });

    return a;
}

console.log(example([{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }]));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCnQC5EwRMAjZAJwG0BdRAH0QG9EB9GAE1PKq0A3IgC+jAJTsAUIjmJ0iALwKAdJnTYCBZFKUA+GfOOIayKCBpIoAT2zI4wFMqUqARHEoArZNDeIAfhRVbh5EUmQRAHooxAA5OChkRCgAC2Tbe0QAcxB0Gh5ZeVEJIWkiuTMLKwUy0XKIBABnOHxVXDhsnQwcfAI6DlDSAFYARgAWACYxABp2Ll4RiYBmMQYJUqA)

Comment: What if I get `a` like so `const a = await doc.find({}, '_id').sort('_id').exec();` where TypeScript can't guess the types, but I know `a` has the structure `[{ _id: 5142 }, { _id: 5143 }]` ?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting - If you know that, tell TypeScript: `const a: { _id: number; }[] = await doc.find(/*...*/).sort(/*...*/).exec();` (if you want to assign the `map` result to something else). (Or if you want to reassign the `map` result back to `a`, define it and the `map` as shown in the `example` function at the end of the answer.)